# i stupidily wrapped my ether to weth from metamask using uniswap,

Tags: transactions, ether, metamask, contract-invocation, pending-transactions

I stupidly wrapped my ether to WETH from MetaMask using Uniswap. I then used https://relay.radar.tech/ to unwrap it but its taking so long. Here is the transaction hash
`0x369d1412b0466fddcbabf431222c41654dd8a01c2bcb0dd43a897aec93a30464`.

If anyone could help I would appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can speed up the transaction and make it go through faster. On MetaMask, click on the transaction that is processing and there will be an option to "Speed up". Click this and it should go through much faster!